# Something like VSS labels in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

What I would like to do is something like this:

When I deliver my code, I would like to label my part of the source with “delivered”.

If other developers follow the same convention,  it should be possible to extract from the scm all the code labelled delivered.

When I deliver code again, it should be possible to move or replace the label delivered on my source.

What is the closest thing you can do in Mercurial, or what is the best convention to follow to keep track of code in specific states as described  above?
(I haven’t actually done a lot of this in VSS, I might actually be mistaken about how it works)

Appendix  1:

I would like that we work in one branch as far as possible, commit and pull/push as much as possible.  Then we need something like labels to keep track of code in a certain state.

Comment: I know about tags and bookmarks.

Comment: I don't thing you can aggregate tags on parts of the source-tree the same way, als I don't think they can be moved the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "aggregate" term mean

Comment: That different parts of the source can be marked seperately, and that it can be threated as one label/tag/bookmark on the whole source.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want named branches.  Each developer can work on their own branch and merge their branch to a "delivered" branch when ready.  When all the developers have merged their branches, the release can be given a final check and tagged.

Comment: I think this would not work if there is code from others in my branch that are not in "delivered" state?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, you want to label individual files in more than one revision. E.g. in revision 1 you label all files in **/lib1/** as "delivered", and in revision 2 you label all files in **/src/** as "delivered". Now if somebody comes along and tells hg to give him all the code that is "delivered", you want in **/lib1/** the files from revision 1, and in **/src/** the files from revision 2.

If this is what you want, it is not possible in hg (and for a good reason: it is considered bad practice). In such a scenario, you could perhaps split the single repo into 2 subrepos "lib1" and "src", versioning both separately. You can then register a certain combination of these 2 sub-repositories by means of a commit in the super-repository, followed by a tag "delivered" in the super-repository.

If you do not want something like this, I don't understand the purpose of labeling only a subset of files in a revision. In this case standard tagging is sufficient, as you can move public tags in Mercurial, anyway (and with history!).

Comment: What exactly is considered a bad practise?

Comment: Versioning files instead of projects and having project consistency only achieved by means of (hand-edited) labels. This was one of the major pains in CVS. Can I consider this comment of yours as acknowledgment of my understanding of your original question?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing in Mercurial is [Tag](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tag).